# Proving that $Gal(K^{\text{sep}}/K)=Aut_{K}(\tilde{K})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

My lecturer told my class to understand the following equality
$$
Gal(K^{\text{sep}}/K)=Aut_{K}(\tilde{K})
$$

Where $K$ is a field, $K^{\text{sep}}$ is the separable closure
within an algebraic closure $\tilde{K}$.

The first thing I'm not sure about is that elements on the RHS are
defined for all $\tilde{K}$ while elements on the LHS are only defined
over $K^{\text{sep}}$.

I think that the intention is to show that if $\sigma\in Gal(K^{\text{sep}}/K)$
then there is only one extension 
$$
\hat{\sigma}:\tilde{K}\to\tilde{K}
$$

s.t
$$
\hat{\sigma}|_{K^{\text{sep}}}=\sigma
$$

What I did is to look at such $\sigma\in Gal(K^{\text{sep}}/K)$,
I have managed to define one extension of $\sigma$ to $\tilde{K}$
by looking at $\tilde{K}$ as a vector space over $K^{\text{sep}}$
and so there is a basis $\{v_{i}\}$ so that if $a\in\tilde{K}$ then
$$
a=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}v_{i_{j}}
$$

and I defined 
$$
\hat{\sigma}(\alpha)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sigma(\alpha_{i})v_{i_{j}}
$$

and this seems to be well defined.

What I wasn't able to do is to prove that if $\sigma_{1},\sigma_{2}\in Aut_{K}(\tilde{K})$
s.t 
$$
\sigma_{1}|_{K^{\text{sep}}}=\sigma_{2}|_{K^{\text{sep}}}
$$

then $\sigma_{1}=\sigma_{2}$.

I would like to use the fact that if $a\in\tilde{K}$ then 
$$
m_{a,K}(x)=p(x)q(x)
$$

where $p(x)$ have no multiple roots and all the roots of $q$ have
multiplicity greater then $1$ (the factorization is made over $\tilde{K}[x]$
as $m_{a,K}(x)$ is irreducible in $K[x]$)

I know that $\sigma$ permutes the roots of $p$, but I'm not sure
what to do about $q$ or how to conclude about how $\sigma$ acts
about $\tilde{K}$ knowing how it acts on the roots of each $p,q$

Can someone help me out with this exercise ?

Comment: This question is related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178455/is-an-automorphism-of-a-normal-extension-determined-by-its-image-of-the-maximal

Comment: This might also help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507891/automorphisms-and-separable-closure/1507942#1507942

Answer (score 2):

If $\overline K = K^{\rm{sep}}$, then the result is clear. Hence, we can assume that $K$ is an imperfect field, and in particular that $\mathrm{char}(K)=p >0$.

The key thing to note is that if $a \in \overline K \setminus K^{\rm{sep}}$, then the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K^{\rm{sep}}$ must be of the form $$q(X) = X^{p^n}-a^{p^n} = (X - a)^{p^n}$$ for some $n$.

In particular, the group of autormorphisms of any finite extension $L/K^{\mathrm{sep}}$ must be trivial, and hence, since $\overline K$ is the union of all such extensions, $\mathrm{Aut}_{K^{\mathrm{sep}}}\overline K$ is trivial. It follows that any $\sigma\in \overline K$ is completely determined by its action on $K^{\mathrm{sep}}$.