# Why the Automorphism group isomorphic to Galois group?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Here is a questions from MIT's Number Theory 1 note.
Here $AKLBG$ setting means $A$ is Dedekind Domain. $K$ is $A$'s fraction field. $L$ is finite separable extension of $K$ and $B$ is integral closure of $L$ over $A$. $G$ means $L/K$ is Galois extension. $D_q$ is decompostion group of prime $q$.

The author shows the separable closure $F$ is normal and hence $F/(A/p)$ is Galois extension. But I don't know how to show the underlined isomorphism... I guess the isomorphism is given by restriction. But I don't know how to show bijection.

[image]

Comment: Can you say more about "MIT's Number theory". Is it a book, an online course ?...

Comment: @JeanMarie A course, but I don't find the course videos. https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2021fa/lectures.html

Answer (score 1):

It is a  fact in field theory that if $K\subseteq L$ a finite normal extension and $S$ is the separable closure of $K$ in $L$, then $\text{Gal}(S/L)\cong \text{Aut}_{K}(L)$. It is trivial when char$K=0$. Assume char$K=p$. Define the natural restriction $f:\text{Aut}_{K}(L)\rightarrow \text{Gal}(S/L)$, $\phi \mapsto \phi|_{S}$. It is well-defined as $\phi(x)\in S$ for $x\in S$. $f$ is surjective since $L/S$ is normal. Now $L/S$ is purely inseparable. For any $x\in L$, there exists $n\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $x^{p^n}\in S$, so $\phi$ on $S$ determines $\phi$ on $L$, so $f$ is bijective.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509877